# Laravel upload Large images

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

I am trying to upload large images to server (binary file upload) via postman, it works fine for files sized 2 MB and below, however for files > 2 MB the upload fails

I set **php.ini**

upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 100M

and

nginx **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

client_body_buffer_size 100M;
client_max_body_size 100M;

but it doesn't work

I tried **plupload** package for chunk upload but it also doesn't work for files > 2 MB

Any ideas how to upload large images in laravel ?

Comment: did you restart the server after you made the changes? does the `phpinfo()` function show the updated values which you did change?

Comment: Thanks  your help, i changed the wrong php.ini file. instead of the  /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini i changed the /etc/php5/cli/php.ini, now the upload works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doen't work because you set the wrong php.ini file
do this on laravel `dd(phpinfo())` and look the right php.ini use by laravel in the value

> Loaded Configuration File

Answer (score 2):

may be I am a bit late for you , but for sake of everyone else , you may consider using this package

[Resumablejs](http://www.resumablejs.com/)

it split file into chunks and upload each one, and if one failed , it will retry until all parts is completely uploaded.

Comment: Or, as a alternative to resumablejs, `tus` is a cross platform protocol that to handle these chunked file transfers.
See https://tus.io