# react js fetch net::ERR_ABORTED 413 (Payload Too Large)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, laravel, csv, fetch

I am sedning large csv file from react to laravel through fetch api but on sending large csv , it sends error

```
fetch net::ERR_ABORTED 413 (Payload Too Large)
```

in fetch i have tried to add properties to add increase size

```
fetch(url, {
        limits:{fileSize: '1gb'},
        headers: {..... },
        body: JSON.stringify({'uploadedData': result.data,limit: '500mb'}),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        console.log(json)
    })
```

but err is still same , 
i found other solution but they are for node and express js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}))
```

Please suggest

Comment: This is a server error from laravel so no use tagging client libraries or node.js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel upload Large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736506/laravel-upload-large-images)